# Trade or exchange items between space engineers of different factions

Tags: space-engineers

In space engineers, how can I exchange items or oxgen/hydrogen between players of different factions?

I know that there isn't any trade logic but I wonder how I can give items to others in a reliable way (without worrying about disappearing items because of the floating object maximum).

- Can I somehow use the connector or do I have to drop items on the ground.
- Can I use cargo containers or tanks that belongs to "nobody"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cargo containers owned by nobody. But you and others can use owned cargo containers as long sharing rights is set to "share with all".

You can't dock to another connector that doesn't belong to you or hasn't it's sharing rights is set to "share with all". But even then you only have access to that connector if nothing else is set to "share with all".